# F(n) is a Fibonacci number. Why do we need two base cases: $n = 3$ and $n = 4$ for the induction to prove $F(n) \geq 2^{(n-1)/2}$ for all $n \geq3?$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality, induction, fibonacci-numbers

F(n) = F(n-1) + F(n-2) is a Fibonacci number(F(1) = 1, F(2) = 1, F(3) = 2 so on...)
I wonder why we need two base cases: $n = 3$ and $n = 4$ for the induction to show $F(n) \ge  2^{(n-1)/2} \;\forall n \ge 3.$
I keep thinking, but I need one base case, $n=3$. I might miss something.

I could see F(3) = 2 is true as (3)≥2
then I could assume that F(k) is true for ≥3
then I could prove $F(n) \ge  2^{(n-1)/2}$ is true for n = +1
as an inductive step. As a result, I could not find out why we need 3 and 4 instead of just 3

Comment: From the recurrence we have $F(4)=F(3)+F(2)$.  Now suppose you assume the result for $n=3$, that is, $F(3)\ge2$, **and nothing else**.  What can you say about $F(4)$?

Comment: Try the induction step. Assum $F(n)\ge 2^{\frac {n-1}2}$.  Now we need to prove $F(n+1)>2^{\frac n2}$.  Okay.  $F(n+1)=F(n) + F(n-1) > 2^{\frac {n-1}2} + F(n-1)$.  But ... we only know $F(n) > 2^{\frac {n-1}2}$.  We don't know *anything* about $F(n-1)$

Comment: "I could see F(3) = 2 is true as F(3)≥2 "  But what about $F(4)$?  David was asking you about $F(4)$.  You have $F(4)=F(3) + F(2) \ge 2^{\frac {3-1}2} + F(2)$ but you don't know *anything* about $F(2)$.

Comment: Conceivably, if you can write a recursion for $F_n$ in terms of $F_{n-1}$ alone (something like $F_n = \varphi F_{n-1}$ rounded in some suitable way), you could do it with just $F_3 = 2$. But I haven't thought about it for more than $10$ seconds to figure out if that would actually work.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: $F(2)=1$ is NOT greater than $2^{(2-1)/2}$, so you need two initial numbers $F(3)$ and $F(4)$ for the induction step.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote by $P(n)$ the property $F(n) \ge  2^{(n-1)/2}$. To prove  $P(n)\;\forall n \ge 3$ you need "two base cases" $P(3)$ and $P(4)$ because the induction step derives $P(n+1)$ not only from $P(n)$: it also needs $P(n-1)$. This is an "induction of order 2". You can view it as a simple induction (of order 1) on $Q(n):=P(n)\land P(n+1)$. The base case is then $Q(3)=P(3)\land P(4)$, and the induction step is $Q(n)\implies Q(n+1)\;\forall n \ge 3$, or equivalently: $Q(n-1)\implies Q(n)\;\forall n \ge4$, i.e. actually $\left(P(n-1)\land P(n)\right)\implies P(n+1)\;\forall n \ge4$

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I didn't put it into words as clearly as I thought I had.

In the induction step to prove $P(n+1)$ we have to calculate $F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$ and we need to assume not *only* that $P(n)$ is true, but also that that $P(n-1)$ is true.  Because we have two assumptions we have to have two base cases for these assumptions.

The thing is:  If you have a single base case $n= n_1$ then the "first" time you apply your induction step all you are assuming is that $n \ge n_1$.  You do that step and to prove $P(n+1)$ you need to assume $P(n)$ and you need to assume $P(n-1)$.  Assuming $P(n)$ is fine because $n \ge n_1$ but assume $P(n-1)$ is *NOT* okay because $n-1 \not \ge n_1$ for all we know. (In fact, the "first" time we do the induction step we are assuming $n = n_1$ so $n-1 < n_1$.)  To handle this we need to introduce a case $n-1 = n_0$ and have the *two* base cases $P(n_0)$ is true and $P(n_1)$ is true.  THen:

... when we do or induction step it goes like this: Assume that $P(n)$ is true and $P(n-1)$ is true (we've covered the base cases of $n=n_1$ and $n-1 = n_0$) the show that $P(n+1)$ is true.

==== edit ====

If you base case is for $n=n_1$ and you want to do an induction step you must assume $P(n)$ is true for $n\ge n_1$ and assume that implies $P(n+1)$ is true.

So if $P(n)$ is true and $n\ge n_1$, that is that $F(n) \ge 2^{\frac {n-1}2}$.

We must prove $F(n+1) \ge 2^{\frac {n}2}$.  Se we try it.

$F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$.  By our induction hypothesis we know $F(n) \ge 2^{\frac {n-1}2}$.   And we *want* to know by the induction hypothesis that $F(n-1) \ge 2^{\frac {n-2}2}$ but .... we *don't* know that.  We *would* know that if we knew $n \ge n_1$ but we don't know that.  We are flummoxed and utterly stuck unless there is a case we can make for $P(n-1)$.  But we just don't have such a case.

We need a case were $P(n_0)$ is true.  ANd where $n_1 = n_0+1$ and $P(n_1)$ is true.  Then we can use our induction step.

Assume we know $P(n)$ is true and $n\ge n_1$ *AND* assume we know $P(n-1)$ is true and $n-1 \ge n_0$.... Now our inductions step is:

$F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$  and because by *one* induction hypothesis, $P(n)$ is true, we know $F(n) \ge 2^{\frac {n-1}2}$ is true.  An by our *OTHER* induction step for $P(n-1)$ we know $F(n-1) \ge 2^{\frac {n-2}2}$ so

$F(n+1)=F(n)+F(n-1) \ge 2^{\frac {n-1}2}+2^{\frac {n-2}2}> ....$ and we can finish.

Comment: However, if I assume that p(n) is true for all 3 =< n =< k, do I still need n = 3 and n = 4 instead of just n = 3?

Comment: Yes, you need it because the "first" time you apply it to $k=4$  and so $P(n)$ is true for all $3 \le n < 4$ (i.e.  $P(3)$ is the *only* one you know) you have to rely on $F(4) = F(3) + F(2)$ and you must assume $P(2)$ and to assume $P(2)$ you need a base case and in this case $P(2)$ is false $F(2) = 1$ and $2^{\frac {2-1}2} = 2^{\frac 12} > 1 = F(2)$.  You can't get $P(4)$ by induction from $P(3)$.  You have to show $P(4)$ as a second base case.