# Is it necessary to show for 2 cases as basis in this proof by induction question?

Tags: induction, recurrence-relations

My A-level textbook has this example:

Given that $u_{n+1}=3u_n+4, u_1=1$ and $n\ge1$, prove by induction that $u_n=3^n-2$

The solution presented is as follows:

$n=1;\,u_1=3^1-2=1$ as given.

$n=2;\,u_2=3^2-2=7$, from the general statement and $u_2=3u_1+4=3(1)+4=7$, from the recurrence relation. So $u_n$ is true for $n=1$ and is also true for $n=2$.

Assume that for $n=k, u_k=3^k-2$ is true for $k\in Z^+$. Then

$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
u_{k+1}&= 3u_k + 4 \\
  &= 3(3^k-2) + 4 \\
  &= 3^{k+1}-6+4\\
  &= 3^{k+1}-2
\end{aligned}\end{equation}$

Therefore, the general statement, $u_n$ is true when $n=k+1.$ If $u_n$ is true when $n=k$, then it has shown that $u_n$ is also true when $n=k+1.$ As $u_n$ is true for $n=1$ and $n=2 \;$ then $u_n$ is true for all $n\ge1$ and $n\in Z^+$ by mathematical induction.

Is the basis for $n=2$ necessary? The assumption steps made use of the fact that if $u_n$ is true for $n=k$, then $u_n$ is true for $n=k+1$. Therefore the basis for $n=1$ is sufficient, in my opinion, cognizant of the fact that $u_1$ is a given value and not obtained from the recurrence formula. Am I wrong? The textbook did explain this though (the rational of which I did not quite get)

** In the basis step of the proof, the general statement was checked for $n=1$ and $n=2$. This is because the first application of the recurrence formula $u_{n+1} = 3u_n+4$ yield $u_2$ by using the first given term $u_1=1$ ***

Comment: You are right. $n=2$ is useless hence highly inelegant.

Comment: You are totally right. The textbook’s explanation for doing the $n=2$ case separate is bogus. Yes, the $n=2$ case is the first time you use the recursive definition, but that also means that for that very case the inductive step applies just fine.

Comment: Hmm, a few days ago a question was asked about a use of induction on the Fibonacci numbers that *did* require two cases.  As $F(n+1) = F(n) + F(n-1)$ we *did* need two cases in order for our induction step assuming not just $P(n)$ being true but *ALSO* $P(n-1)$ being true.  But in this case as your recurrence is only one deep, you only need one case.  (In general if you had a recurrence $k$ deep [ex.  $a_n = 3a_{n-1} + 4a_{n-2} + 4a_{n-3}^2$ would be three deep] you would need $k$ base cases)

Comment: You may want to look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841228/fn-is-a-fibonacci-number-why-do-we-need-two-base-cases-n-3-and-n-4-f/4841249#4841249 for a case where you *do* need two base cases. But, again, your example isn't such a case.  (A side note.  Sometimes it's good to have some extra cases just to be "sure" and to not make assumptions about the base case having properties that don't apply [The famous "all horses are the same color" error is based one assuming the base case $n=1$ has the property that $n-1 > 0$].  Having extra cases prevent dumb errors. But aren't needed.])

Comment: @fleablood Thank-you. Yes, the textbook example following the one I posted indeed showcased a recurrence formula that is "2" deep and uses 3 cases n=1, n=2 and n=3 as basis  basis (which I thought require only two).  The replies to my post convinces me that the book has erred in this regard.

Comment: Hmm, I suspect the author is trying give extra cases "just to make sure".   Sometimes the inductive step on the base case is trivial and sometimes the inductive step requires the case be more than the base case and I know trying to teach and explain that subtlety to a novice can be difficult and frustrating, so maybe the author is just trying to avoid the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There are situations where your argument for A(n) => A(n+1) is not valid say for n = 3, only for n >= 4. In that situation you would need to show A(1) to A(4).

In your case, the induction step is correct for n = 1 so no need to show A(2).

Answer (score 0):

If you have a recursive definition, then the inductive proof can just follow that very definition: The non-recursive base cases become the cases for the inductive base, while for the recursive cases you can follow the inductive step.

So, since in your case the value for $u_n$  is defined non-recursively only for $n=1$, you only have to check the proposition for $n=1$ as the inductive base. Since the values of $u_n$ are recursively defined for $n\geq 2$, the inductive step will verify the proposition exactly for those $n \geq 2$ using the very recursive definition for those cases.